# fixed-top navbar cuts off half at top on mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

On desktop the navbar stays fixed to the top, with no issues when scrolling. However when I pull up the site on my phone/use chrome devtools, the navbar initially loads fine until I begin scrolling which causes the navbar to float up to (what seems) the top of the device which ends up cutting off about 50% of the navbar.

I began by commenting out some of my custom css that I wrote for the navbar to see if that fixed it, it didnt. So than I jumped in and wrote media queries for what I thought might be causing the issue. That didn't help(other than finally getting me to write the media queries I should have been the entire time). I then found a resource saying I just needed to add an offset/margin-top to fix the issue however that did nothing either.

```html
<nav id="navbar-scrollspy" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top scrolling-navbar nav-sm-query">
```

Expected Result: Navbar stays fixed-top to the current viewport on mobile[image: correct appearance]

Actual Result: Navbar appears to fixed-top to top of device causing navbar to be cut by 30 - 75%[image: bugged navbar]

Comment: Did you end up finding a good solution to this?

Answer (score 8):

This may relate to your viewport settings in your `<head>`. Try adding 'minimum-scale=1' to the viewport meta.

So for example, my viewport settings now look like the following, and I no longer lose the top 50% of a fixed position navbar.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Can you share how you came to this solution? Scaling seems a bit unrelated to the fixed navbar, but it does work. However, it does also prevent user scaling though, so my users can no longer zoom in to increase font size :/

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the z-index value on the navbar class.

CSS:

```
.navbar {
   z-index: 9999; // <=== Add this.
 }
```

Comment: Added this to .navbar both in a media query for small sized screens and smaller and outside. Nothing changed, I also included a offset(some extreme number to see if it was working)  and then a margin-top and a padding-top (also extreme numbers) and it also didnt make a difference.

Comment: try adding padding top to the body inside css on monile only. body { padding-top: 40px }

Comment: This worked kinda, i isnt perfect by any means but if it keeps the navbar from getting cut off oh well. It is amazing how you try something once and it doesnt work but do it again and it finally works. Thanks!